# How to write a custom function for extracting predictions from `effects::Effect()`

Tags: r, function, regression, prediction, multinomial

I want to write a function that takes in data and runs a multinomial regression (using `nnet::multinom`), then extracts a focal prediction (using `Effects::effect`). While I'm able to get it done with regular code, a custom function fails.

## Example

### Background

I conduct a research to find which type of color people like the most: red, green, or blue. I sample **200** people, and ask them to choose the one color they like the most. Because I suspect that some variables might confound the results, I measure them as well: **(1) sex**, **(2) color blindness**, and **(3) age**.

### Method

I will run a multinomial regression using `nnet::multinom` and then extract a *focal* prediction from that model (using `Effects::effect`) which will account for *specific* values for sex, color blindness, and age.

### Data

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(2020)

df <-
  data.frame(person_id = 1:200,
             chosen_color = sample(c("red", "green", "blue"), size = 200, replace = TRUE),
             age = sample(18:80, size = 200, replace = TRUE),
             is_colorblind = sample(c(0, 1), prob = c(0.2, 0.8), size = 200, replace = TRUE),
             is_female = sample(c(0, 1), prob = c(0.3, 0.7), size = 200, replace = TRUE)
           )

as_tibble(df)

## # A tibble: 200 x 5
##    person_id chosen_color   age is_colorblind is_female
##        <int> <chr>        <int>         <dbl>     <dbl>
##  1         1 blue            57             1         0
##  2         2 blue            51             1         0
##  3         3 blue            38             1         1
##  4         4 red             30             1         1
##  5         5 green           78             1         1
##  6         6 red             72             1         0
##  7         7 green           63             1         1
##  8         8 green           69             0         0
##  9         9 red             57             1         0
## 10        10 blue            20             0         1
## # ... with 190 more rows
```

### What is the proportion of popularity for each color?

#### (A) The simple yet likely inaccurate method

Just find the most frequent color in `chosen color`:

```r
df %>%
  group_by(chosen_color) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  mutate(freq = n / sum(n))

## # A tibble: 3 x 3
##   chosen_color     n  freq
##   <chr>        <int> <dbl>
## 1 blue            76  0.38
## 2 green           60  0.3 
## 3 red             64  0.32
```

Since I want to find insights that are general to the entire population, I have little faith in the accuracy of the table I got. This is because my sample is not representative. In my sample, 20% of the people are colorblinded and 70% are female. If I have a reason to believe that sex and colorblindedness might influence color popularity, then this sample is problematic.

#### (B) Accounting and correcting for sample (un)representativeness

Using regression I can: (1) model the relationship between color preference and demographics variables, and (2) predict a "corrected" average response based on the demographic values that occur in the population (but not necessarily in my sample). Since my variable of interest is nominal, I'm using a multinomial regression (with `nnet::multinom`).

**1. Fit the model**

```r
library(nnet)

fit <-
  nnet::multinom(chosen_color ~ age + is_colorblind + is_female,
                 data = df)
```

**2. Define a vector with the "corrected" values as they happen to be in the population level, to use in the prediction step.**

- **age** -- I know that the average age in the population is 45.
- **sex** -- I know that sex is roughly at 50% split, thus 0.5.
- **color blindness** -- I know that on average, 2% of the population is color blinded (say). Hence 0.02.

```r
one_average_person <- 
  c(age = 45,
    is_female = 0.5,
    is_colorblind = 0.02
  )
```

**3. Use a prediction function to get a focal prediction for each color, given the values in `one_average_person`.**

I've found only `effects::Effect` to play well with a model generated from `nnet::multinom`. Still, since I couldn't find a straightforward way to get a focal prediction for the values I specify, I ended up with a workaround. In the following code, `age` is the "focal" predictor, but I also specify the other variables using the `given.values` argument. Furthermore, I can't just ask for `age = 45` because `Effect` cannot take a single value, so I ask for a prediction for both `age = 45` and `age = 90`. Then I remove the prediction for `90` because I don't need it.

```r
library(effects)

prediction <- 
  effects::Effect("age", 
                  fit, 
                  given.values = one_average_person, 
                  xlevels = list(age = c(45,90)))


wrangled_prediction_data <-
  data.frame(prediction$prob, prediction$lower.prob, prediction$upper.prob) %>% 
  slice(1) %>%  ## <----- here I remove the unnecessary prediction for age = 90
  pivot_longer(., cols = everything(), 
               names_to = c(".value", "response"), 
               names_pattern = "(.*)\\.(.*$)") %>%
  rename("lower_ci" = "L.prob",
         "upper_ci" = "U.prob",
         "estimate" = "prob")


> wrangled_prediction_data

## # A tibble: 3 x 4
##   response estimate lower_ci upper_ci
##   <chr>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1 blue        0.474    0.328    0.625
## 2 green       0.290    0.172    0.445
## 3 red         0.236    0.129    0.391
```

The values in the table reflect the popularity of each color, when accounting for the situation in the population level.

### Writing a function to streamline the regression + prediction process above

While I had to do some gymnastics with `Effect` to get what I need (please give feedback on that if you see a better way than my awkward code), I want to write a function to make this work more concise.

### My unsuccessful function

As you can see, I'm limited to using `age` as a predictor, so I ended up building the function around `age`. In reality, this is far from ideal, because not always will I have age in my data. But my function is not working regardless of that. The reason for this difficulty is that "age" is entered as a string in `focal.predictors` argument, but as a variable in `xlevels` (within a list). I tried using double curly brackets ([of tidy evaluation](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/#a-simpler-interpolation-pattern-with-)), but still unsuccessful.

```r
require(dplyr)
require(nnet)
require(effects)

analyze_multiple_choice_w_age <-
  function(data,
           vars_demog,
           vars_dv,
           age_var_for_Effect,
           ave_age,
           one_ave_person_vec) {
    fit <-
      data %>%
      nnet::multinom(
        data = .,
        formula = as.formula(
        paste(
          vars_dv,
          paste(names(select({{ data }}, vars_demog )), collapse = " + "),
          sep = " ~ "
        )) 
        )
    
    prediction <-
      effects::Effect(
        focal.predictors = age_var_for_Effect,
        mod = fit,
        given.values = one_average_person,
        xlevels = list(age_var_for_Effect = c(ave_age, 90)
        )
      )
    
    return(prediction)

  }
```

Any ideas on making this function to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a version of your function that works if you provide all variable names as strings:

```
set.seed(2020)

df <-
  data.frame(person_id = 1:200,
             chosen_color = sample(c("red", "green", "blue"), size = 200, replace = TRUE),
             age = sample(18:80, size = 200, replace = TRUE),
             is_colorblind = sample(c(0, 1), prob = c(0.2, 0.8), size = 200, replace = TRUE),
             is_female = sample(c(0, 1), prob = c(0.3, 0.7), size = 200, replace = TRUE)
  )

require(dplyr)
require(nnet)
require(effects)
library(rlang)

analyze_multiple_choice_w_age <-
  function(data,
           vars_demog,
           vars_dv,
           age_var_for_Effect,
           ave_age,
           one_ave_person_vec) {
    fit <-
      data %>%
      nnet::multinom(
        data = .,
        formula = as.formula(
          paste(
            vars_dv,
            paste(vars_demog, collapse = " + "),
            sep = " ~ "
          )) 
      )
    
    prediction <-
      effects::Effect(
        focal.predictors = age_var_for_Effect,
        mod = fit,
        given.values = one_ave_person_vec,
        xlevels = list2(!!age_var_for_Effect := c(ave_age, 90)
        )
      )
    
    return(prediction)
    
  }

test <- analyze_multiple_choice_w_age(
  data = df,
  vars_demog = c("age", "is_colorblind", "is_female"),
  vars_dv = "chosen_color",
  age_var_for_Effect = "age",
  ave_age = 45,
  one_ave_person_vec = c(age = 45,
                         is_female = 0.5,
                         is_colorblind = 0.02
  )
)


test

age effect (probability) for blue
age
       45        90 
0.3030466 0.2604459 

age effect (probability) for green
age
       45        90 
0.3992617 0.5270109 

age effect (probability) for red
age
       45        90 
0.2976917 0.2125432
```

What I changed:

- `as.formula` can directly work with strings, so I simplified this
- from `rlang`, I use `!!` to force the evaluation of `age_var_for_Effect` to use this as the variable name in the list. You can use `:=` from `rlang` to assign a (forced) name as the variable name of a list, however this does not work in the normal `list` but in `rlang::list2`